# How do I generate a list-of-Foos/index-of-Foos, for a non-environment foo

Tags: table-of-contents

In my document, I talk about Foo's in various ways; sometimes through a definition environment; sometimes just mentioning them inline; sometimes in other ways. What are Foo's? Never you mind. Maybe it's a specific macro/command; maybe it's something entirely abstract (to which I could theoretically add a phantom marker if necessary).

How would I generate a "List of Foos" or "Index of Foos", with identifiers of Foos and the pages they're in?

Comment: Have a look at the package tocbasic. You can create an own toc with that and just use `\addcontentsline` with custom content.

Comment: @TeXnician: Would that allow for something that's index-like? i.e. with lexicographic sorting and spacing between Foos starting with different letters?

Comment: No that would be a "List of Foos". For new indices look at `splitidx`.

Comment: @TeXnician: Can you make an answer out of your comments?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example giving you `listOfFoos`:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{#1%
\addcontentsline{new}{subsection}{#1}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listOfFoos}{\section*{List of foos}\@starttoc{new}}
\begin{document}

\listOfFoos
\foo{Dave}
\foo{Nate}
\foo{Pat}
\foo{Taylor}
\foo{Chris}
\foo{Rami}
\end{document}
```

and here's an example using `imakeidx`

```
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: on}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}

% index stuff
\makeindex
\makeindex[name=myindex,title=index of foos]

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{#1%
\index[myindex]{#1}}
\begin{document}

\foo{Dave}
\foo{Nate}
\foo{Pat}
\foo{Taylor}
\foo{Chris}
\foo{Rami}
\printindex[myindex]

\end{document}
```

Note that in the case of `imakeidx` you'll need to use `shell-escape`.